# Additional Line in my Chapter

Tags: chapters

I did not notice when the additional unwanted LINE at the upper part appeared. 
I have changed from Article, Report and Book but in vain. 
These are my code of chapter I used for the style ( I forgot from where I copied from). FYI, the language is Khmer ( Cambodian)

```
      \makeatletter
      \let\stdchapter\chapter

  \renewcommand*\chapter{%
\@ifstar{\starchapter}{\@dblarg\nostarchapter}}
  \newcommand*\starchapter[1]{%
\stdchapter*{#1}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}
   }
 \def\nostarchapter[#1]#2{%
\stdchapter[{#1}]{#2}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
 }
 \makeatother
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is because of use `\thispagestyle{fancy}` is this necessary?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Sorry and I know I had to do it but the packages  I use are too many that I no longer know which is relavant. That is why I thought I should not put.

Comment: @touhami Yes! Thanks for you hint. It conflicted with 
       \thispagestyle{plain} . After I edited \thispagestyle{fancy} to empty and add \thispagestyle{plain} for my main text, it works.

Comment: @touhami Do you want to write up an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to `\thispagestyle{fancy}` in

```
\newcommand*\starchapter[1]{%
\stdchapter*{#1}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}
 }
```

or

```
\def\nostarchapter[#1]#2{%
\stdchapter[{#1}]{#2}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
 }
```

I think one can remove it and use `\pagestyle{plain}` for the whole document